# JavaScript only working if the web is refreshed, not the first time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Javasciprt not working the first time, if the web is reload is working fine, cant find the error i am not using timeout or something similar, only document ready

i cant find the error i tried others events like document on load or autorefreshing the web 1 time, but the last one its not working ebcause its not doing the javascript the first time like i say ;(

the jquery script:

```
  <script>
    if (window.location.href.indexOf(".com/courses") >= 0) {


        $(document).ready(function () {



            jQuery.noConflict();



            $(".atr458").hover(function () {
                $(".atr458").css("color", "#09A59A");

            });

            $(
                "body > div.view-school > div > div > div.row.course-list.list > div:nth-child(7) > div > div.course-listing-extra-info.col-xs-12"
            ).html(
                "<a class='ahre55' href=''>Mas Informacion</a>"
            );


            $(
                "body > div.view-school > div > div > div.row.course-list.list > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.course-listing-extra-info.col-xs-12 > div:nth-child(3) > div"
            ).html(
                "<a class='ahre55' href=''>Mas Informacion</a>"
            );

            $(
                "body > div.view-school > div > div > div.row.course-list.list > div:nth-child(3) > div > div.course-listing-extra-info.col-xs-12 > div:nth-child(3) > div"
            ).html(
                "<a href='' class='ahre55' >Mas Informacion</a>"
            );


            $(
                "body > div.view-school > div > div > div.row.course-list.list > div:nth-child(5) > div > div.course-listing-extra-info.col-xs-12 > div:nth-child(3) > div"
            ).html(
                "<a class='ahre55' href=''>Mas Informacion</a>"
            );

            $(
                "body > div.view-school > div > div > div.row.course-list.list > div:nth-child(6) > div > div.course-listing-extra-info.col-xs-12 > div:nth-child(3) > div"
            ).html(
                "<a class='ahre55' href=''>Mas Informacion</a>"
            );


            $(
                "body > div.view-school > div > div > div.row.course-list.list > div:nth-child(8) > div > div.course-listing-extra-info.col-xs-12 > div:nth-child(3) > div"
            ).html(
                "<a class='ahre55' href=''>Mas Informacion</a>"
            );

            $(
                "body > div.view-school > div > div > div.row.course-list.list > div:nth-child(9) > div > div.course-listing-extra-info.col-xs-12 > div:nth-child(3) > div"
            ).html(
                "<a class='ahre55' href=''>Mas Informacion</a>"
            );


            $(
                "body > div.view-school > div > div > div.row.course-list.list > div:nth-child(2) > div > div.course-listing-extra-info.col-xs-12"
            ).append(
                "<a class='atr458' id='atr457' href=''>Aplicar Aquí</a>" //COMPELTAR CON LINK 
            );
            $(
                "body > div.view-school > div > div > div.row.course-list.list > div:nth-child(10) > div > div.course-listing-extra-info.col-xs-12"
            ).append(
                "<a class='atr458' id='atr457' href=''>Aplicar Aquí</a>" //COMPELTAR CON LINK
            );

            $(
                "body > div.view-school > div > div > div.row.course-list.list > div:nth-child(11) > div > div.course-listing-extra-info.col-xs-12"
            ).append(
                "<a class='atr458' id='atr457' href=''>Aplicar Aquí</a>" //COMPELTAR CON LINK
            );

            $(
                "body > div.view-school > div > div > div.row.course-list.list > div:nth-child(12) > div > div.course-listing-extra-info.col-xs-12"
            ).append(
                "<a class='atr458' id='atr457' href=''>Aplicar Aquí</a>" //COMPELTAR CON LINK
            );
            $(".atr458").css("left", "30%");
        })
    }


    jQuery.noConflict();

</script>
```

Comment: Try moving the script tag after the body.

Comment: i cant do it because i am on host only admit js inside head

Comment: try moving the conditional inside the document.ready

Comment: tried and nothing

Comment: Then inject the script after body instead of the head.

Comment: also - you have 2 jquery.NoConflicts ... ?

Comment: like i said before i dont have access

Comment: right sorry my mistake xd

Comment: You don't need to have access to inject the script to another part of the page.

Comment: Where are you loading jQuery? Is that in the head also? Do you have control over the order of script elements in the head?

Comment: yea i have order of script in head

Comment: maybe move the script to body by script ? .-.

Comment: i just checked some wird thing, if i go directly to the link is working all the time but if i go by an a html element href, its not working

Comment: "if i go by an a html element href, its not working"  When you navigate via that href link, does the URL contain the string ".com/courses"?  (I'm wondering if the link is including a hash or the like, or a case-sensitivity problem, that is causing your url test to fail)

Comment: maybe the if condition its not okay? the href is /courses

Comment: You could easily check that by putting an `else { console.log(...)}` on that condition...